# mono.security.dll novell.directory.ldap.dll Secure Socket Layer - SSL

Tags: ssl, mono, ldap, novell, edirectory

Imported certificates like this:

```
certmgr /add /v /c /ctl "selfsignedroot.cer" /s /r localMachine root
certmgr /add /v /c /ctl "server.cer" /s /r localMachine root
certmgr /add /v /c /ctl "server.cer" /s /r localMachine CA
certmgr /add /v /c /ctl "server.cer" /s /r localMachine MY
```

My code looks like this

```
LdapConnection conn = new LdapConnection();
conn.SecureSocketLayer=true;
conn.Connect("server",636);
conn.bind("cn=user,o=root","password");
```

I get error comming from mono.security.dll. Error code: -2146762487. Which means it failed to validate root certificate. Looking at the certificate via mmc it is shown as trusted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Mono.Security.dll` is cross platform and its origins are on Linux. As such it does not use Windows CryptoAPI-based certificate stores, but it's own stores (and tools).

You can look at the Mono project's wiki, e.g. the [security FAQ](http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ%3a_Security), and in particular the article named [Using Trusted Roots Respectfully](http://www.mono-project.com/UsingTrustedRootsRespectfully).